# MySQL extract a single word from a text field

Tags: mysql, text

Here is what my table looks like

```
----------------------------+-----------+
| tw_dt                          | text                                                                                                                                         | ID        |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Thu Dec 12 19:14:13 +0000 2013 | #CoSignCountdown airs MON-FRI @7p send in your hottest song to cosigncountdown@gmail.com Original music ONLY!!! #TEAMFOLLOWBACK @HipHopDotCA |  14985388 |
| Thu Dec 12 19:14:12 +0000 2013 | "Get any Beat at http://t.co/R61XJ5EYUQ for $200 each. Exclusive Rights. To pruchase - GummyBeatz@Gmail.com"                                 | 170900539 |
| Thu Dec 12 19:14:09 +0000 2013 | "@iwantmixedbabys PREMO is looking for Models for the SuperBadd fashionshow January10th 3000 EXPECTED email us premopresents@gmail.com"      | 343062689 |
| Thu Dec 12 19:14:09 +0000 2013 | mixtape hosting contact . bookdjlyrical@gmail.com                                                                                            |  99644471 |
| Thu Dec 12 19:14:09 +0000 2013 | checkout http://t.co/4f2txyVpLy  RIGHT NOW!!!! #Artist send in music and videos to preciseearz@gmail.com #BlogsAreTheNewMixtapes             |  27872863 |
| Thu Dec 12 20:01:10 +0000 2013 | ATTENTION ARTISTS: DO YOU NEED US TO HELP YOU PROMOTE YOUR MUSIC?!? EMAIL US FOR OUR PROMO PACKAGES AT VIEWHIPHOP@gmail.com                  | 357913081 |
| Thu Dec 12 20:01:10 +0000 2013 | RT @ITSMIKESWAGGER: @Mike_Bell1 no doubt my artist appreciates the love mikeswagger@gmail.com hit me up                                      | 165499064 |
| Thu Dec 12 20:01:10 +0000 2013 | @grandst @cmj_333  - swking1964@gmail.com is my Santa - but just needs to be aware of your site in General! Happy Holidays!                  | 574317429 |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I want to extract the email address from the text as it's own column.

Any thoughts on how I accomplish this in MYSQL?

Comment: Is the email address always at `gmail.com` or is your sample data misleading?

Comment: it can be others so the sample is a bit miss leading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's this [huge regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for matching e-mail addresses. Combined with the regex replace solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql), you should be good to go.